# single quote in front of bit concatenation in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
logic[1:0] a;
logic[1:0] b;
assign a = {1'b0, 1'b1};
assign b = '{1'b0, 1'b0};
```

Is there a difference between having ' in front of {} in Verilog/SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. As soon as you put the `'` in front, you no longer have a concatenation; you have an assignment pattern. There are many cases where the result looks the same, but the main difference is in a concatenation, each operand is evaluated in a self-determined context, and in an assignment pattern, each operand is in a context of an assignment to each element in the pattern. Take this modified example:

```
assign a = {2'b1,2'b0}; // result is 4'b0100, a == 2'b00
assign b = '{2'b1,2'b0}; // result is b[1] = 2'b1, b[0] = 2'b0; b == 2'b10
```

The width of the concatenation is 4-bits and gets truncated to 2-bits. 
In the assignment pattern, each operand gets truncated from 2 to 1 bits.

Concatenations have other features not available in an assignment pattern, like replication `a = {2{1'b1}};` Assignment patterns have features not available in concatenations, like index labeling `b = '{0:1, 1:0};` b = 2'b01. This feature becomes very useful in structures and associative arrays. For example

```
string AA[int] = '{0:"zero", 1:"one",2:"two",default:"undefined"};
```

AA[0], AA[1], and AA[2] return "zero", "one", and "two" respectively. But any other index returns the string "undefined"

Comment: Huh.  I actually had never run into index labeling before.  Verilog continues to accrete features.  Won't be long now before it can send email.